# macroing on android (without touchscreen)

Tags: android-tv

I have used repetitouch in the past to record touches for use in macros.  I have been trying to do the same on my android tv box however repetitouch doesnt sense any input and so it records, but then when played back nothing happens.

Are there any input recorders that would record keyboard and mouse strokes?

Mainly trying to accomplish 2 task (in case there is another approach I'm not thinking of)

- automate web page from entries and submission
- automate resource collecting in COC

Comment: If you can elaborate what you want to achieve in detail i might be able to suggest Tasker or MacroDroid for automation

Comment: not sure whats missing from above.  i indicate that i need something that will record keyboard and mouse strokes, to auto mate web page form entries, and resource collection in COC.  Tasker usually would use repetitouch files to launch apps and simulate touches, however it doesnt record keyboard and mouse input, so i need an alternative

Comment: If touch doesn't work you may try using directional keys and tabs to move to a place and perform actions by tasker or MacroDroid